# AWS Lex and Facebook typing animation

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I made a chatbot in AWS Lex and deployed it to facebook. However, I want the chat to display a typing animation before the bot replies. Right now the bot just replies instantly. I want there to be a typing animation to make the bot been more human like.

Is there some setting in FB Developer I can turn on? I can't seem to find it anywhere. All I see are things for the API call but I am not using any REST calls in my chatbot.

Answer (score 0):

What if you wait 1 second before sending the message?

Comment: What do you mean wait 1 second?